# Connect to Windows Server 2008 running on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows

I have an instance of the default micro AMI for Windows Server 2008 R1 x32 running on AWS. I can remote in to it, but I can't seem to `ping` it or connect to a server running on port `25565`. I have associated the instance with an elastic IP, and I've set the security groups so the `25565` port is open. What else can I try?

Comment: Have you configured the Windows firewall to allow connections to this port?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check your firewall group once again.

Allo ICMP from there.
Then allow the specific port.

Also if you can do remote desktop then you must be seeing port 3389 open there